# Filtering on object property with checkbox with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have an ng-repeat list displaying multiple properties of an array of objects and the possibility to filter it using input fields.

What I didn't manage to do is to implement the possibility to filter the results using a checkbox and the existance or not of a specific object.property.

Basically I want it to display the results where record.cancelled = true when the checkbox is checked, and all the results if it remains unchecked.

Heres my HTML:

```
   <div class="row msf-row" 
     ng-repeat="record in recordlist | filter: search" 
     ng-class="{ 'msf-cancelled': record.cancelled}">
      <div class="col-md-1">{{record.time}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><strong>{{record.car}}</strong></div>
      <div class="col-md-2">{{record.driver}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-2">{{record.from}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-3" ng-show="editItem == false" ng-hide="editItem">{{record.destination}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-3" ng-show="editItem == true" ng-hide="!editItem">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="record.destination" ng-options="location.place as location.place for location in locationlist | orderBy:'place'">
          <option value="">Destination</option>
        </select> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 msf-centered" ng-show="editItem == false" ng-hide="editItem">{{record.pax}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-1" ng-show="editItem == true" ng-hide="!editItem">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="record.pax">
            <option>Driver</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
          </select>
      </div>
```

And the current filter:

```
    <div class="col-md-12 msf-filter">
        <div class="row">
          <form role="form">
            <div class="col-md-1 msf-date">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Time" ng-model="search.time">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Car" ng-model="search.car">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Driver" ng-model="search.driver">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="From" ng-model="search.from">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Destination" ng-model="search.destination">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Pax" ng-model="search.pax">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.cancelled"> Cancelled 
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

So far, when I check the checkbox, it will filter the results correctly, but when I uncheck, it will display no results at all (when it should be displaying all of them).

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you provide JSfiddle with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is the following:

1. At first `search.cancelled` is `undefined`.
2. When you click the checkbox the first time, the value changes to `true`.
3. If you click again the value will change to `false`, so the filter searchs for
   elements where `record.cancelled == false`.

One way to get around this problem is to use the ng-change attribute for the checkbox element like this:

```
ng-change="search.cancelled = search.cancelled ? true : undefined"
```

In the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.cancelled" ng-change="search.cancelled = search.cancelled ? true : undefined">
```

Check out this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pmc9etpk/)**

Comment: This works perfectly for a boolean property like search.cancelled, which is true or undefined, but I can't manage to do the same for another property which has a string. I have also a checkbox for search.comment which is supposed to filter if the .comment property exists or not...